# Menu control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight navigation application. I am looking for a simple one level menu control that pops down the page header and provides links to other pages. How to implement it. Is there any such control in Silverlight 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight does not have a built in menu control, however, many people have creates there own:

http://www.nablasoft.com/guardian/index.php/2008/09/25/silverlight-how-to-build-a-simple-menu-control/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/DropDownMenuSilverlight2.aspx

http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2008/08/21/coolmenu-a-silverlight-menu-control.aspx

http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com/

sl4popupmenu looks like one of the best.